# Does anybody know where to find very detailed NBA player salary data?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a very specific kind of dataset or a website that documents this data. I need data for NBA players' salaries ideally going back 30 years. I've found some sites that have the data, but they don't go into enough detail. I would like the data to include a marker that says when a new contract is signed and a number specifying how much of the contract is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

https://nbasalary.sportsdada.net/

Check the links here.
The Kaggle set goes back almost 30 years.